# How to create an ipa and run application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipa

I have my new macbook air.
I have created one test application.
now i want to create ipa file for my application.
but archive button in product menu is not enable.
How to create ipa for this?
and another thing is that i want to run this Application in my iPhone instead of simulator.
How can i do so??
please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make .ipa file read this [Creating .ipa file](http://www.codepo.st/2012/04/18/how-to-create-ipa.html).

You need to have Apple's developer account, which will cost you 99$. Then you will be able to make certificates and use them to check the app on your mobile.

How to make certificates, [read here](http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/checklist.html)

This will help you alot ....

Answer (score 2):

You will need to purchase a license from apple, then follow the tutorial they have on their website and everything should go just fine

Without the license, certificates and keys, you will not be able to run the application on your iPhone/iPad

[iOS developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/)

Answer (score 1):

For enabling archive button in product menu select iOS device instead of iOS simulator in scheme.